# Examples of module with both finite and infinite free resolutions

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative algebra, can we find a $R$-module $M$ that has both finite and infinite free resolutions?

I know that one can always obtain an infinite free resolution from a finite free resolution by keep adding $0\rightarrow R \xrightarrow{id} R \rightarrow 0$.

However, I hope to know some "non-trivial" examples. Namely, infinite free resolutions that are not obtained by adding exact sequences to finite free resolutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what happens with free resolutions. But if $M$ has a finite projective resolution, then any infinite *projective* resolution is obtained by adding an exact sequence of projectives to a finite projective resolution:

Suppose $M$ has finite projective dimension $d$, and
$$\dots \to P_2 \to P_1 \to  P_0 \to M \to 0 \tag{$P$}$$
is a (possibly infinite) projective resolution. Set $P_d' = \operatorname{ker}(P_{d-1} \to P_{d-2}) = \operatorname{im}(P_d \to P_{d-1})$, then
$$0 \to P_d' \to P_{d-1} \to \dots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0 \tag{$P'$}$$
is again a projective resolution.

*Exercise*: Use the resolution $(P)$ to show that all $\operatorname{Ext}$-groups involving $P_{d}'$ vanish, so $P_d'$ is projective.

Since $P_d'$ is projective, the surjection $P_d \to P_d'$ splits, i.e. $P_d \cong P_d' \oplus P_d''$, and $P_d'' = \operatorname{im}(P_{d+1} \to P_d)$. This means, that the resolution $(P)$ is the direct sum of the finite resolution $(P')$ and the exact sequence
$$\dots \to P_{d+2} \to P_{d+1} \to P_d'' \to 0. \tag{$P''$}$$

However if all the $P_i$'s are free, $P_d'$ need not be free, so I'm not sure what happens then.

Comment: Thanks. One could have a projective module with infinite free resolutions. Like $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_6$-module. For free resolutions, it seems like we have way less "freedom" to maneuver them without breaking the "freeness".